# Why does the noun слепой decline like an adjective?

Tags: падежи, склонение

As shown by the declension table for the noun version of слепой here: [https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/слепой](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9) this word apparently is a noun (blind person) but declines like an adjective (prepositional case is слепом and not слепое* as I would expect under the rules I've seen, yet this is not marked as irregular on Wiktionary). Why? Is this a special case where an adjective can act as a noun but stays declining as an adjective?

Comment: in grammatical terms it's called **substantivized adjective** which as a grammatical category also exist in [English](http://englishstyle.net/grammar/adjective/substantivized-adjectives/) although i'm not sure whether it's recognized in the native English grammar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some adjectives that have become nouns as a result of dropping the nominal part of the noun phrase. These adjectives have the semantic meaning of the noun phrase and retain **the gender of the dropped noun**, but keep their **adjectival declension**.

> Русский,больной, ученый,мороженое,рабочий, насекомое, животное, шампанское.

Comment: A few feminine examples: столовая, вселенная, запятая. Plural: лёгкие, данные.

Comment: one which goes well together with мороженое is **пирожное**, other culinary items are **заливное, жаркое**, from zoology **млекопитающее, пресмыкающееся** although these are rather  substantivized present participles

Comment: thank you for the explanation and the examples. I was surprised I couldn't find this topic covered in the grammar by Terence Wade